# Im creating a range slider in react native. Im having trouble getting the labels to update live (while I scroll), rather than when I finish scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

This is what my slider component looks like.
[image: example1]

[image: example2]

When I slide the knob, it doesn't update the value. However, I want it to update my AnimatedTextInput live, not just when I let go of the knob. I'm relatively new to React Native. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const AnimatedTextInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TextInput);

export const SliderRange = ({min, max, onValueChange}) =>{

const knob1 = useSharedValue(0);
const knob1x = useSharedValue(0);
const scaleKnob1 = useSharedValue(1);

const knob2 = useSharedValue(MAXWIDTH);
const knob2x = useSharedValue(MAXWIDTH);
const scaleKnob2 = useSharedValue(1);

const styleLine = useAnimatedStyle(()=>{
    return{
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
        height:6,
        marginTop:-5,
        borderRadius:10,
        width:knob2.value-knob1.value,
        transform:[{translateX:knob1.value}]
    }
});

const onDrag1 = Gesture.Pan()
.onBegin(() => {
    knob1x.value = knob1.value;
})
.onChange((event) => {
    scaleKnob1.value = 1.3
    knob1.value = event.translationX + knob1x.value < 0 ? 0 : event.translationX + knob1x.value >  knob2.value-20 ? knob2.value-20: event.translationX + knob1x.value;
})
.onEnd(()=>{
    scaleKnob1.value = 1;
    runOnJS(onValueChange)({
        min:`${Math.round((min+((knob1.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min))))}`,
        max:`${Math.round((min+((knob2.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min))))}`
    })
});

const onDrag2 = Gesture.Pan()
.onBegin(() => {
    knob2x.value = knob2.value;
})
.onChange((event) => {
    scaleKnob2.value = 1.3
    knob2.value = event.translationX + knob2x.value < knob1.value+20 ? knob1.value+20 : event.translationX + knob2x.value > MAXWIDTH ? MAXWIDTH: event.translationX + knob2x.value;
})
.onEnd(()=>{
    scaleKnob2.value = 1;
    runOnJS(onValueChange)({
        min:`${Math.round((min+((knob1.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min))))}`,
        max:`${Math.round((min+((knob2.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min))))}`
    })
});

const styleKnob1 = useAnimatedStyle(()=>{
    return{
        transform:[{translateX: knob1.value}, {scale:scaleKnob1.value}]
    }
});

const styleKnob2 = useAnimatedStyle(()=>{
    return{
        transform:[{translateX: knob2.value}, {scale:scaleKnob2.value}]
    }
});

const propLabel1 = useAnimatedProps(()=>{
    // console.log(Math.round((min+((knob1.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min)))))
    return{
        value: `${Math.round((min+((knob1.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min))))}`
    };
})
const propLabel2 = useAnimatedProps(()=>{
    return{
        text:`${Math.round((min+((knob2.value/MAXWIDTH) * (max-min))))}`,
    };
})

return(
    <View>
        <View style={styles.rangeContainer}>
            <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                <AnimatedTextInput defaultValue={`${min}`} editable={false} style={styles.label} animatedProps={()=>{propLabel1}}/>
                <AnimatedTextInput defaultValue={`${max}`} editable={false} style={styles.label} animatedProps={propLabel2}/>
            </View>
        <View style={styles.track} />
            <Animated.View style={styleLine} />
            <GestureHandlerRootView>
                <GestureDetector gesture={onDrag1}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.knob, styleKnob1]}/>
                </GestureDetector>
                <GestureDetector gesture={onDrag2}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.knob, styleKnob2]}/>
                </GestureDetector>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
        </View>
    </View>
)}
```

I've tried useRef and useEffect, but they only update the text after I've released the knob, not while I'm scrolling it.

Comment: You can use ReText instead of the text inputs

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ReText could you elaborate how to use ReText please